# Remove item from DataSource when DataList ItemCommand is fired

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

Im a little stuck here. I have a datalist which has a datasource thats a Lit (of SomeObject).

```
Private MyObjectList As List (of SomeObject)
```

I load data as and when required by the user clicking a button to add a product to their shopping basket and bind the datalist.

```
Form_load....
dl.Datasource = MyObjectList
dl.databind()
End Sub
```

To display data in the datalist i have a label which shows what theyve added, using the e eventArg casting it to my object, example below:

```
Protected Sub dl_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dl.ItemDataBound
    Dim myObject = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, SomeObject)
....
Label.Text = myObject.Description

End Sub
```

The inline code is:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeletePRoduct" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Del" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

So now i would like the user to be able to delete a product

```
Protected Sub dl_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dl.ItemCommand
    Dim myObject = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, SomeObject)

    If e.CommandName = "Del" Then
        MyObjectList.Remove(myObject)
    ....
    End If
End Sub
```

If i try and pass in myObject under the ItemCommand i realised that e.item.DataItem that i casted is Nothing so it doesnt delete any products. I then thought to remove that product by row index and added a CommandArgument to the button when i realised i cant do that as the List expects a type of SomeObject.

Could anyone advise how to remove an object in this manner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ID of deleting item using `dl.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]`. Make sure to set `DataKeyField` of `DataList` control.

[image]

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID"...>
 ....
</asp:DataList>

Public Class SomeObject
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set
            m_ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
End Class

Private _someObjects As List(Of SomeObject)
Public Property SomeObjects() As List(Of SomeObject)
    Get
        If _someObjects Is Nothing Then
            _someObjects = New List(Of SomeObject)() With { _
                New SomeObject() With { _
                    .ID = 1, _
                    .Name = "One" _
                }, _
                New SomeObject() With { _
                    .ID = 2, _
                    .Name = "Two" _
                }, _
                New SomeObject() With { _
                    .ID = 2, _
                    .Name = "Three" _
                } _
            }
        End If
        Return _someObjects
    End Get
    Set
        SomeObjects = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        dl.DataSource = SomeObjects
        dl.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub dl_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Del" Then
        Dim id = Convert.ToInt32(dl.DataKeys(e.Item.ItemIndex))
        Dim someObject = SomeObjects.First(Function(x) x.ID = id)
        SomeObjects.Remove(someObject)

        dl.DataSource = SomeObjects
        dl.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** you need to take care of the persistence of data after deleting. For example, storing data in ViewState, Session or Database.

Comment: Thank you - that did the trick. I really appreciate you taking the time to demo this too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind `DataList` again after removing object from data source `MyObjectList` to get the updated records on page.

```
If e.CommandName = "Del" Then

    MyObjectList.Remove(myObject)
    dl.Datasource = MyObjectList
    dl.databind()
....
End If
```

Comment: Thats the problem how do i delete the object, that the user clicked the Delete button against? As e.Item.DataItem under the ItemCommand event for the DataList control is Nothing, so casting it made no difference?

Comment: How you populate data in MyObjectList, you may use data base (table in database) as data source.

Comment: I use a List (Of SomeObject) as the datasource, this is then bound against the Datasource of the DataList. In order for me to remove an item im checking the "e" variable event in ItemCommand which is nothing?